# What to use for user profile search: username or JWT token?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jwt

In my web application, I want to go to the user home page or profile page of another user.

What should I pass to query data for a particular user ?

What should be the flow ?

I am trying to build a full stack JS application with user profiling.

Comment: Why would you even consider using a JWT token? Tokens are for authentication, are usually short-lived, and any given user only knows its own token - it should not have access to other users' tokens.

Comment: Okay. I will use "username" & set it to unique. (1)   Do we need to send the JWT token with every request for authentication ? I am little confused. Like, I logged into & received a JWT. Now for every next request I should also send this in HTTP req body & server will authenticate that I am a valid user ? (2) Should I store all user profile data in the same schema or create a different one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good choice would be to choose the user property that matches the following rules :

- be unique (required)
- never change (recommended, if not, provide a 404 redirect)

So often the username is used. 
If you provide a way to change the username, the User UID would be less  semantic but will work.

Comment: (1) Do we need to send the JWT token with every request for authentication ? I am little confused. Like, I logged into & received a JWT. Now for every next request I should also send this in HTTP req body & server will authenticate that I am a valid user or invalid ? If I am invalid, it returns an error, but if valid it will return the requested data ?

Comment: It depends on your authentication strategie. Both are possible. If you use server sessions, no need to send explicit auth information on each request (cookie-session handles it), but if not, you are in a State-less pattern that require authentication on each request